# Search cursor stops selecting after two iterations

Tags: python, arcmap, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a script which selects an extent from a grid and exports the data frame.

```
import os, arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
grid_lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"grid")[0]
scur = arcpy.SearchCursor(grid_lyr)

for row in scur:
    sqlExp = """{0} = '{1}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(grid_lyr,"PageName"),row.getValue("PageName"))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(grid_lyr,"NEW_SELECTION",sqlExp)
    print "Selecting {}".format(row.getValue("PageName"))
    df.extent = grid_lyr.getSelectedExtent(False)
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    df.scale = df.scale*1.05
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,os.path.join(r'C:\temp\109147',row.getValue("PageName")+".tif"),df,817, 534,world_file=True)

    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del scur, mxd
```

I ran this script last week, and it crashed ArcMap after exporting the first tiff. I then ran it in a blank ArcMap document, changed `CURRENT` to the full path and it worked (all 414 tiff files exported).

I am running the same script again today, on the same data, from a blank document. It now successfully exports the first two tiffs, and then stops executing as if it is finished, without any errors. When I try to run it again, ArcMap crashes again. I am not sure what the problem is, last week when it failed I just opened a blank document, as that normally solves the issues half the time.

I updated the code to include print statements for debugging:

```
for row in scur:
    print "Row count: " +str(arcpy.GetCount_management(grid_lyr))
    sqlExp = """{0} = '{1}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(grid_lyr,"PageName"),row.getValue("PageName"))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(grid_lyr,"NEW_SELECTION",sqlExp)
    print "SQL is: {}".format(sqlExp)
    df.extent = grid_lyr.getSelectedExtent(False)
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    df.scale = df.scale*1.05
    print "Data frame {0} has a scale of {1}".format(df.name, df.scale)
    name = os.path.join(r'C:\temp\109147',row.getValue("PageName")+".tif")
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,name,df,817, 534,world_file=True)
    print "Exported {}".format(name) 
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

del scur, mxd, row
```

The output was:

```
Row count: 500
SQL is: "PageName" = 'E3'
Data frame Layers has a scale of 2276.80888604
Exported C:\temp\109147\E3.tif
Row count: 1
SQL is: "PageName" = 'E4'
Data frame Layers has a scale of 2276.80888604
Exported C:\temp\109147\E4.tif
```

My grid layer only has 414 features, so the row count numbers are a bit weird. Also, if I try to define the cursor variable again in the same session, ArcMap crashes.

Comment: Are you deleting your search cursor and row objects?

Comment: Yes I am, forgot to add in the last line.

Comment: What about the row object (del row)?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that no records are selected in grid_lyr when you start the script?  If anything is selected when you get going ONLY those records will show up in the cursor.

Comment: @artwork21 I've checked and realised I did not have that in my script, although it ran fine without it last week. I'll add in `del row` now and check if it works.

Comment: @Kevin there is no selection on the layer, when it did work last week I ran it inside a blank mxd so the layer was not present.

Comment: @artwork21 It still only runs the first two rows, exports the images, and then finishes executing.

Comment: It sounds like your process is "running out of resources" but what resources I cannot say. To avoid any ArcMap overhead have you tried running it, with the necessary modifications, from ArcCatalog, from an IDE or the DOS prompt?

Comment: A colleague took the same script and ran it in ArcMap 10, and it worked, no adjustments made. I tried running it from Eclipse and I got the same issue. It seems like it was by chance that the script worked once last week, after about the 5th try, and has not worked correctly since.

Comment: I would recommend throwing in a handful of print statements that will show you the values of your variables for filenames and paths. It's inelegant and pretty much a brute-force technique but I've often found it the fastest way to debug arcpy scripts.  I would recommend using arcpy.GetCount_management() to show how many records are being recognized in your layer, a counter to show how many times you're going through the for loop, and an output of all your filename/path variables.  Then run the script and dig through all the output when it quits.  You may find the culprit somewhere in there.

Comment: Try separating your del row object and indenting it within your for loop.

Comment: @artwork21 ArcMap now crashes after running the first two selections successfully. Actually, now that I've placed the `del row` object in the same place it was before, it still crashes after running the first two selections!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar behaviour which I found out has to do with the arcpy.mapping site package. Since its the newest part in arcpy and is implemented as a wrapper for ArcObjects, it has problems in its error handling capabilities. Calls to arcpy.mapping may crash very often. And also if you try to catch exceptions, that does not work, because exceptions are never thrown. It simply kills the python interpreter. I told this to the ESRI support and they accepted it as a Bug (NIM090073). Hopefully it will be fixed with the next ServicePack.

You can easily check if this also happens here if you uncomment the Line

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,name,df,817, 534,world_file=True)
```

The cursor loop should finish then. Also you can check with a python debugger if the script crashes on the above line.

As a workaround our ESRI distributor told us to install ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 for Desktop Background Geoprocessing (64-Bit) from [here](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1913#choose-product) . Of course you need ArcGIS 10.1 with Service Pack 1 installed and you need a 64-Bit machine, but that helped so my arcpy.mapping script ran through without problems.